# ElasticSearch randomly fails when running tests

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a test ElasticSearch box (2.3.0) and my tests that are using ES are failing in random order which is really frustrating (failed with All shards failed exception).

Looking at the `elastic_search.log` file it only showed me this

```
[2017-05-04 04:19:15,990][DEBUG][action.search.type       ] [es-testing-1] All shards failed for phase: [query]
RemoteTransportException[[es-testing-1][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: IllegalIndexShardStateException[CurrentState[RECOVERING] operations only allowed when shard state is one of [POST_RECOVERY, STARTED, RELOCATED]];
Caused by: [derp_test][[derp_test][3]] IllegalIndexShardStateException[CurrentState[RECOVERING] operations only allowed when shard state is one of [POST_RECOVERY, STARTED, RELOCATED]]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.readAllowed(IndexShard.java:993)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.acquireSearcher(IndexShard.java:814)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:641)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:618)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:369)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:368)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:365)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.doRun(TransportService.java:350)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
```

Any idea what's going on? So far my research only told me this is most likely due to corrupt translog -- but I don't think deleting translog will help because the test drops the test index for every namespace

ES test box has 3.5GB RAM and it's using 2.5GB heap size, CPU usage is quite normal during the test (peaked at 15%)

---

To clarify: when I said failing test, I meant error with the weird exception as mentioned above (not failing test due to incorrect value). I did manual refresh after every insert/update operation so value is correct.

Comment: Are you using [ESIntegTestCase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/integration-tests.html) for your integration test?

Comment: @chengpohi no, currently it's just treating the test box as a normal es box.. Is this an anti-pattern or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investigating ElasticSearch log file (at DEBUG level) and the source code, turns out what actually happened was that after index is created, the shards are entering `RECOVERING` state and sometimes my test tried to perform a query on ElasticSearch while the shards are not yet active -- thus the exception.

Fix is simple - after creating an index, just wait until shards are active using `setWaitForActiveShards` function and to be more paranoid I also added `setWaitForYellowStatus`

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Forgot about it due to the 2 days delay before accepting own answer 

Answer (score 0):

It's a recommendation use [ESIntegTestCase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/integration-tests.html) to do the integration test.

`ESIntegTestCase` has some helper method, like: `ensureGreen` and `refresh` ... to ensure the **Elasticsearch** is ready to continue testing. and you can configure `node settings`  for test.

if use `Elasticsearch` directly as a test box, it maybe cause various problems:

1. like your `Exception`, this seems it's recovering shards for index 
   `derp_test`.
2. even you have indexed your data into index, but when you immediately search will fail, since cluster need **flush** or **refresh**
   ...

Those most problems can just use `Thread.sleep` to wait some time to fix :), but it's a bad way to do this.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure if I can use `ESIntegTestCase` easily in this case because it's a clojure project and ES is just one part of the equation. I'll see if I can fiddle around with flush/refresh to solve this issue

Comment: Yes, you should try this with **synchronous** operation.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually refreshing your indices after inserting the data and before performing a query to ensure the data is searchable.

Either:

- As part of the index request - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/docs-index_.html#index-refresh
- Or separately - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/indices-refresh.html

Comment: oops my bad, I should've make it clearer, when I said "failing test" I meant error rather than giving invalid result. I also did refresh after every insert/update

Answer (score 0):

There could be another reason. I had the same problem with my elasticsearch unit tests, at first I thought the problem root cause is somewhere in .Net Core or Nest or elsewhere outside of my code because the test would **run successfully** **in Debug mode** (When debugging tests) but **randomly failed in Release mode (when running tests)**.

After lots of investigations and many try and errors, I found out the **problem root cause** (in my case) was **Concurrency !!** or on the other hand **Race Condition** used to happen

Since the tests run concurrently and I used to recreate and seed my index (initializing and preparing) on test class constructor which means executing on the beginning of every test and since the tests would run concurrently, race condition were likely to happen and make my tests fail

Here is my initialization code that caused tests fail randomly when running them (on release mode)

```
 public BaseElasticDataTest(RootFixture fixture)
        : base(fixture)
    {
        ElasticHelper = fixture.Builder.Build<ElasticDataProvider<FakePersonIndex>();
        deleteFakeIndex();
        createFakeIndex();
        fillFakeIndexData();
    }
```

the code above used to run on every test concurrently. I fixed my problem by executing initialization code only once per test class (once for all the test cases inside the test class) and the problem went away.

Here is my fixed test class constructor code :

```
 static bool initialized = false;
 public BaseElasticDataTest(RootFixture fixture)
        : base(fixture)
    {
        ElasticHelper = fixture.Builder.Build<ElasticDataProvider<FakePersonIndex>>();
        if (!initialized)
        {
            deleteFakeIndex();
            createFakeIndex();
            fillFakeIndexData();
            //for concurrency
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            initialized = true;
        }

    }
```

Hope it helps